# Eclipse WTP, maven and m2eclipse - not copying provided jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

When using Eclipse WTP and m2eclipse it is possible to copy all dependencies to WEB-INF/lib (by adding "maven dependencies" in the Deployment assembly). However, dependencies with scope "provided" are also copied, for example el-api and jsp-api. That disturbs the container and it fails to start.

Any solution for not copying the "provided" jars?

Comment: I think you will have to manually remove them from your eclipse Deployment assembly. This is eclipse specific & don't think Maven plays a part here.

Comment: there is no exclusion option. It's just "add all maven dependencies"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to install the `m2eclipse-wtp` <del>which is an extra plug-in for m2eclipse</del> .It will do this job for you. After installing the m2eclipse-wtp , just right-click `project ---> Maven --> Update Project Configuration` , you will find that the libs of the provided scope will not be distrusted to the WTP container anymore.

See [this](http://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/06/23/m2eclipse-wtp-0130-new-noteworthy) for the installation instruction. I would suggest to install the latest version of m2eclipse-wtp (tested against Eclipse 3.6 +)  as it solves some  major bugs in the previous versions.

Edit: Thanks Fred for the correction

Comment: Ken, just a minor correction : m2e-wtp is not technically a part of m2eclipse-extras anymore, but a standalone project. Since 0.13.1 however (http://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/08/01/m2eclipse-wtp-0131-back-to-the-m2e-marketplace), it requires the mavenarchiver 0.14.x+ feature from m2eclipse-extras, which should be installed automatically from the m2e-wtp's update site (http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/)

Comment: m2eclipse-wtp is deprecated in favor of m2e-wtp.

Comment: I also had to add <packaging>war</packaging> into pom.xml for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Maven Library to WTP's Deployment Assembly...

Right click on your project, select "Properties"

From the properties menu click "Deployment Assembly"

Click "Add" -> "Java Build Path Entries" then click "Next"

Select "Maven Libraries" on the list and click "Finish"

Comment: good ! another way could by the following: Click "Add" -> "Folder" then click "Next" select "target/<appname>/webapp/WEB-INF/lib and then edit the destination folder as "WEB-INF/lib"

Comment: @FabioMarano Your solution is actually better because it does not deploy the dependencies that have a "provided" or "runtime" scope.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies of scope "provided" *shouldn't* be packaged by Maven in the final assembly.

However, check if you have other dependencies that are "compile" that also declare those same dependencies as "compile". In other words, it's very likely that `el-api` and `jsp-api` are being pulled in as transitive dependencies.

Easiest way to check is using the Dependency Hierarchy view of m2eclipse.

Comment: they are not fetched as transitive dependencies. They are declared in our pom, with scope "provided", but m2eclipse fails to recognize the scope and just copies everything.

Comment: Oh, so you're packaging from within Eclipse, not using Maven. So indeed it's m2eclipse + WTP, that's the problem. Sorry, didn't read thoroughly.