# Maven provided scope and eclipse runtime classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven, classpath, m2e

I've got a problem with my eclipse classpath with the m2e plugin.
I have a project which depends on other projects in my workspace. I've added these dependencies as maven dependencies with scope provided. I expect the scope to do the following: 
Provide the dependencies for compilation but exclude them for the runtime classpath.
Because at runtime, these classes should be loaded from jars inside a folder.

But the eclipse classpath includes every single dependency I've provided in the project pom.
Eclipse seems to ignore the provided scope.
Is there any way to exclude those from runtime classpath?

Regards

Comment: You may find the following StackOverflow thread helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979513/eclipse-wtp-maven-and-m2eclipse-not-copying-provided-jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m2e is doing its job properly here. I think you misunderstand the meaning of 'runtime'. Your project does in fact depend on the other projects at both compile and runtime and when you build it with Maven, the POM will reflect that. You would only use scope 'provided' if you were planning to deploy the project to e.g. an application server that provides the dependencies itself.

Comment: Ok, so if I use Maven, there is no way to exclude dependencies from the eclipse classpath as long as they are a dependency in the project pom. What can I do then? Since the whole classpath in eclipse consists only of the maven dependency container I have to edit the classpath manually but I guess this isn't the best practice here.

Comment: But why do you want to exclude dependencies from the eclipse classpath?

Comment: Because these classes should be loaded from jars. It's an architectural problem.

Comment: If you want to force m2e to load dependencies from the maven repo instead of other eclipse projects, choose 'Disable workspace resolution'. But that negates many of the advantages of integrating Maven with Eclipse. I'm still unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to exclude a maven dependency in the eclipse classpath at runtime to include these classes at runtime as a plugin (form a jar). If they are already on the classpath before the jar is loaded, the respective classes are not replaced by the jar.

Comment: In that case you should add the plugin jar to the run configuration's classpath, and then move it so that it is above the Maven Dependencies in the list of User Entries. That means classes will be resolved from your jar first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want dependencies to be "provided for compilation but excluded from runtime classpath" you need to use the "provided" dependency *scope* (a Maven term) rather than the "compile" scope, which Maven uses by default.

Comment: The OP said he did exactly that. The problem is this only works outside of Eclipse, but it won't help during development in Eclipse as per the original question. JDT has no concept of different classpath scopes, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376616 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356450

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem with maven-war-plugin version 2.2, use maven-war-plugin ver. 2.3 the problem is gone, at minimum with **mvn package** command.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>

            <configuration>
                <webxml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webxml>
                <packagingExcludes>jsp-api-6.0.36.jar,el-api-6.0.36.jar,servlet-api-6.0.36.jar</packagingExcludes>              

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```