# loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V"

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, jdeveloper

I got this error while deploying the WAR in Tomcat 7. I have carried out the development using JDeveloper 11.

> "java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type p.JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V used in the signature"

I have googled for the answers and have found answers, but nothing seems to work for my problem. I understand that it is something to do with the JARs that I have in my `/WEB-INF/lib`, but I don't know which causes the error.

These are the JARs I have in `/WEB-INF/lib`:

- `adf-controller-api.jar`
- `adf-controller-rt-common.jar`
- `adf-controller-security.jar`
- `adf-controller.jar`
- `adf-dt-at-rt.jar`
- `adf-richclient-api-11.jar`
- `adf-richclient-impl-11.jar`
- `adf-share-base.jar`
- `adf-share-ca.jar`
- `adf-share-security.jar`
- `adf-share-support.jar`
- `adf-transactions-dt.jar`
- `adfdt_common.jar`
- `adflibfilter.jar`
- `adflogginghandler.jar`
- `adfm.jar`
- `adfmweb.jar`
- `adfsharembean.jar`
- `cache.jar`
- `commons-el.jar`
- `db-ca.jar`
- `dvt-databindings.jar`
- `dvt-faces.jar`
- `dvt-facesbindings.jar`
- `dvt-jclient.jar`
- `dvt-trinidad.jar`
- `dvt-utils.jar`
- `glassfish.el_2.2.0.jar`
- `glassfish.jsf_1.2.9.0.jar`
- `glassfish.jstl_1.2.0.1.jar`
- `groovy-all-1.6.3.jar`
- `identitystore.jar`
- `inspect4.jar`
- `javatools-nodeps.jar`
- `javax.activation_1.1.0.0_1-1.jar`
- `javax.ejb_3.0.1.jar`
- `javax.jsf_1.0.0.0_1-2.jar`
- `javax.jsp_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar`
- `javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar`
- `jdev-cm.jar`
- `jewt4.jar`
- `jsp-el-api.jar`
- `ojdbc14.jar`
- `ojmisc.jar`
- `oracle-el.jar`
- `oracle-page-templates.jar`
- `share.jar`
- `trinidad-api.jar`
- `trinidad-impl.jar`
- `wls.jsf.di.jar`
- `xmlparserv2.jar`

How can I solve it?

Comment: I think it is because of jsp-el-api.jar. Did you try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761249/loader-constraint-violation

Comment: Thanks thinksteep, yes it was i have removed the jar and now it is find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** have servletcontainer-specific libraries in your `/WEB-INF/lib`. At least the following ones are supposed to be *already* provided by Tomcat itself:

- `glassfish.el_2.2.0.jar`
- `javax.jsp_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar`
- `javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar`
- `jsp-el-api.jar`

Remove them. The particular exception is caused by the `javax.jsp_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar` one, which is different from Tomcat's own one.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project) (not related to JDeveloper, but it should give you the right picture as to how to manage libraries in any IDE).

Comment: Thanks Balus , it was the jsp-el-api.jar which was giving me problems have removed it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when migrating a project from WAS6 to WAS 7. Here is the fix:

1. Update web.xml:
   a.  Open Project_name\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
   b.  Add the following listener:

   Com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

c.  Build the project and deploy it to Websphere

1. Change loader order:
   a.  Open Websphere application server Console
   b.  Go to: Applications >> Application Types >> WebSphere enterprise applications 
   c.  Click at the project 
   d.  Click “Class loading and update detection”
   e.  Choose “Classes loaded with parent loader first”
   f.  Click Apply
2. Disable JSP class reloading
   a.  Go to: Applications >> Application Types >> WebSphere enterprise applications 
   b.  Click at the project 
   c.  Click at JSP and JSF options
   d.  Uncheck “JSP enable class reloading”
   e.  Click OK
3. Change JSF Implementation
   a.  Go to: Applications >> Application Types >> WebSphere enterprise applications 
   b.  Click at the project 
   c.  Click at JSP and JSF options
   d.  Choose “MyFaces 1.2” under JSF Implementation
4. Start the Project