# What are servletcontainer specific libraries?

Tags: java, jar, servlet-container

In posts like https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076706/5467214 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743562/5467214 I keep reading about "servletcontainer specific libraries", that shouldn't be included manually in JavaEE projects, if I understood it correctly. Libraries like `servlet-api.jar`, `jsp-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, `j2ee.jar` or `javaee.jar` are mentioned, but normally followed by an "**etc.**".

Is there a good explanation what "servletcontainer specific" means or perhaps an exhaustive list of which libraries are servletcontainer specific for Catalina, for example? Or for other servletcontainers? For example, `jstl-1.1.2.jar` gets explicitely loaded via the `pom.xml` in a project I am working on that runs on a Tomcat7. Is this "servletcontainer specific library"?

Comment: Aren't they libraries you need to run a specific servletcontainer?

Comment: Is that so? I have no idea, that's why I am asking ;)

Comment: Here is the answer for you mostly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703840/tomcat-casting-servlets-to-javax-servlet-servlet-instead-of-jakarta-servlet-http/65704617#65704617