# LinkageError: loader constraint violation:

Tags: java, classloader, jboss6.x, linkageerror, sslsocketfactory

Help me how to solve this one?
i'm doing Netsuite integration with java,i added required jar files to my project.
After adding jars deployed in jboss 6.1.0.After adding this jar org.apache.sling.commons.log-2.0.6.jar  getting following exception.
This my stack trace.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext.getSocketFactory()Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/axis/components/net/SunJSSESocketFactory, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, com/sun/net/ssl/SSLContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory used in the signature
    org.apache.axis.components.net.SunJSSESocketFactory.initFactory(SunJSSESocketFactory.java:83)
    org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:79)
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

Comment: The following questions and you are very similar，hope to help you.
[loader constraint violation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761249/loader-constraint-violation

Comment: not useful for me...Alan  anyone suggest me how to solve this one..

Answer (score -1):

I just got the solution for this. I have removed ibmjsse.jar file from my classpath and then I have found it working.